# query case when postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, case-when

I have query like this :

```
select
    case when code=31 then name end as name1,
    case when code=32 then name end as name2
from master where code=31 or partner_id=32
```

and the result just like this :

[image: query result]

I want to make just 1 row but 2 column which is the value is like the table above.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select max(case when code=31 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when code=32 then name end) as name2
from master
where code = 31 or partner_id = 32;
```